# Can't use MapServer to create custom basemap or ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-online

I have a NZ MapServer, that has "Single Fused Map Cache: true", yet I am unable to use it for custom basemap or ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer.

This works:

```
esriBasemaps.customBasemap = {
  baseMapLayers: [{url: "https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Specialty/DeLorme_World_Base_Map/MapServer"}],
  title: "customBasemap"
};

var map = new Map("map", {
  basemap: "customBasemap", 
  center: [172.62982, -43.523158], 
  zoom: 17
});
```

This doesn't:

```
esriBasemaps.customBasemap = {
  baseMapLayers: [{url: "https://services.arcgisonline.co.nz/arcgis/rest/services/Imagery/newzealand/MapServer"}],
  title: "customBasemap"
};

var map = new Map("map", {
  basemap: "customBasemap", 
  center: [172.62982, -43.523158], 
  zoom: 17
});
```

I've seen a couple of people suggesting to use ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer instead, but that would mean I draw a map and then another on top of it, so I'd like to use it as a Basemap.

Can someone please tell me what I am missing?

Comment: Functionally, in the JSAPI 3.x, there's no difference between adding it as ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer or custom basemap. Both are being used the same way.

Answer (score 1):

I think the NZ service is working, but you're zooming in to the wrong area since that NZ map service isn't in latlong or webmercator spatial reference.

If you remove the "center" or "zoom" property, does it work?

Maybe try with something more NZ-ish, like:

```
center: new Point(1412345, 5212345, new SpatialReference({ wkid: 2193 })),
zoom: 3
```

Comment: Thanks very much @Bjorn, this was it! Your suggestion worked like a charm. I actually ended up creating a point from JSON, just so I can save two dependencies and to have a bit shorter "require" section :)

`center: { "x": 1570079.412818821, "y": 5181017.619741657, "spatialReference": { "wkid": 2193 }}`